# How to check if directory on path is empty?

Tags: go, directory

How to check in Go if folder is empty? I can check like:

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(*folderName)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// here check len of files
```

But it kinda looks to me that there should be more a elegant solution.

Comment: You could do [`f.Readdir(1)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) to only look at the first directory entry (or 3 if you need to skip "." and "..") (helpful if there may be many many directory entries). But beware, you can only ever know "if the directory *was* empty", it may have new files in it by the time you check. That's probably one reason no such "easy" check exists; because it's pretty useless. [E.g., that's why things like `rmdir` don't check, they just try and remove the directory and handle/report `ENOTEMPTY` instead since that's atomic.]

Comment: ^^ actually [`f.Readdirnames(1)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames) (or 3) would be slightly better.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Whether a directory is empty or not is not stored in the file-system level as properties like its name, creation time or its size (in case of files).

That being said you can't just obtain this information from an [`os.FileInfo`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo). The easiest way is to query the children (content) of the directory.

[`ioutil.ReadDir()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir) is quite a bad choice as that first reads all the contents of the specified directory and then sorts them by name, and then returns the slice. The fastest way is as Dave C mentioned: query the children of the directory using [`File.Readdir()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) or (preferably) [`File.Readdirnames()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames) .

Both `File.Readdir()` and `File.Readdirnames()` take a parameter which is used to limit the number of returned values. It is enough to query only 1 child. As `Readdirnames()` returns only names, it is faster because no further calls are required to obtain (and construct) [`FileInfo`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) structs.

Note that if the directory is empty, `io.EOF` is returned as an error (and not an empty or `nil` slice) so we don't even need the returned names slice.

The final code could look like this:

```
func IsEmpty(name string) (bool, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    _, err = f.Readdirnames(1) // Or f.Readdir(1)
    if err == io.EOF {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, err // Either not empty or error, suits both cases
}
```

Comment: `File.Readdirnames()` implementation seems to be based on `File.Readdir()`.

Comment: For now better to use File.ReadDir() ?

Comment: As for golang:1.19 it's better to use `File.Readdirnames()` because its implementation just reads names, while `File.Readdir` reads each found file statistics as well. See https://go.dev/src/os/dir_windows.go line 40

Comment: @MikhailKopylov It's exactly what the answer suggests.

Comment: Exactly. Just added a link explaining why